# How can i make two spans be in the same line with 'display:block' on

Tags: html, css

I've got the following column header and i want it to be displayed like the following

> ```
> Known allergies Peanut Ace...
> ```

ie the line shortned with ellipses.

My code works but it puts one span underneathe the other when i add `display:block` to the style.

it now displays like this

> ```
>     Known allergies
> ```
>
> Peanut Ace...

How can I display it in the same line

```
<th border="0" >
    <span width="100%" onclick="dropdownResize()" style="padding-top:2px; white-space: nowrap; font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;
        <i>Known allergies </i>&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="allergiesSpan" style="white-space: nowrap; display: block ; overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; width:50%;"> 
    <b>Peanut, Aceti test test test tes test</b>&nbsp;</i></span>       
</th>
```

Comment: Why do you want to have them be on the same line, and have display:block set? Why not just keep them inline?

Comment: @marcin  overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; does not work unless theyre in block

Answer (score 4):

You could `float: left;` the part which has `display: block;`

```
<th border="0" >
    <span width="100%" onclick="dropdownResize()" style="padding-top:2px; white-space: nowrap; font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;
        <i>Known allergies </i>&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="allergiesSpan" style="white-space: nowrap; display: block ; float: left; overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; width:50%;"> 
    <b>Peanut, Aceti test test test tes test</b>&nbsp;</i></span>       
</th>
```

Comment: it does not work.peanut etc is on the left now but above it and a bit more to the right is  'known allergies'

Comment: Sorry, this is nigh on impossible to fix without having some more information - can you provide a "demo" or a screenshot would work as well...?

Comment: @Neurofluxation your code makes it display like this (the info on the pic is made up) http://i.imgur.com/FidN8.jpg instead i want it to be in the same line as 'known allergies'

Answer (score 4):

use display:inline-block; instead of display:block

Al

Comment: It does support inline-block for elements that are originally inline (like spans) http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html Also if IE6 support is required text-overflow:elipses won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`display: block;` causes the element to be as wide as its' parent. You'll have to assign a width to both elements if they both are `block` and need to be next to eachother.

I see also that your example code gives the first `span` a width of `100%`. This may contribute to the problem of the second element being pushed down.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have both span elements be in a block div, with style "overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;". That way, the overflow will still be hidden, but your elements will be layed out next to each other?

Comment: even that pushes the second span down

Comment: Even if the spans are left displaying inline, and you stop setting the width of the first one to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

I haven´t seen the rest of the html, but as you are using a table, why don´t you just put the two different blocks of information in two different table cells?

If the ellipses on the `th` itself is not working, you can always add a block level element in the table cell.